# Ionic-1 Navigation

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic-1 App. I am terrible confused in managing the back history of my app. Consider this scenario:

1. Start from home page then
2. Does a 3 step user registration process
3. After the end of user registration redirect to records page

Now clicking back button (hard or soft back) I want to navigate back to home instead of cycling through user registration process. There are other scenarios like this where back behavior needs to be modified. Are there any references around to implement back behavior systematically? Should I manually define view hierarchy tree structure and somehow figure out where in tree current view is and then go to parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my suggestion you should pass parameter say 'extraparams' in your url and set it value to 'home'.And on record page controller  then make a function on  back button say 'goBack()' where you can check if value of 'extraparams' is 'home' and then use $state.go() to navigate to home view.

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep and maintain each and every section using state approach then you can redirect to home page or what ever the page you prefer to redirect to.In that way you have to implement back button like this way, $state.go('homeSate');

or if you can keep 3 steps(registration) as sub states and have try by injecting  $rootScope to your controller in which allows you to access your parent(home).